# Capture event in a function to stop it from bubling

Tags: javascript, event-bubbling

Note: I now about event bubling and how to stop it.

Code ==>

```
function foo ( bar ){
//do something
}
```

In the above function,i want to capture the `event` so I can stop it from bubling out.

What i've tried so far -->

**Try 1**

```
function foo ( bar,event ){
//do something
}
```

**Try 2**

```
function foo (bar ){
if( window.event || event )
   // code to stop bubling

//do something
}
```

Not using **jQuery**, vanilla js solution required.
Using [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) method for prevention of event bubling.

-- beginner.

Comment: Where is the event coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function foo ( bar,event ){
  if (event.stopPropagation) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    event.cancelBubble = true;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Tried it,dint work - please read the question - i've already mentioned that i've tried it!!

Answer (score 0):

```
elem.onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WnSjb/

Comment: I know how to stop it, i've also given a reference to the method on how to stop event bubling. You have to have the object `event` or `window.event` to send stop it from bubling. I want to capture that!!.

Comment: @VivekChandra Well your original code has a few mistakes I fixed.. first of all, you are just defining a function - not adding an event listener. Secondly, the event object is sent as the first argument to the function. So, if you have  `.onclick = function( bar, event ) {}`, `bar` will be the event object if the argument is sent. The rest is `undefined` because only one argument is passed.